# upgrading 1.1 Framework to 4.0

Tags: .net, asp.net, frameworks

I guess i'm wondering if i need to upgrade one version at a time (2.0, 3.5, 4.0) or if I can just directly from 1.1 to 4.0?  Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean? Are you upgrading an application which was written for 1.1, or are you installing the 4.0 framework on your computer which has 1.1 installed?

Comment: Are you converting an existing .NET application from 1.1 to 4.0? Depending on the complexity, I might take it one step at a time (1.1 to 2.0, then to 4.0), but I don't see why you couldn't try going straight to 4.0 from 1.1.

Answer (score 4):

You can install the new version of the framework next to the existing one, so both are available. (That's the default --- It's actually a bit of work to get rid of the old one).  The latest will install all the files it needs.

Note that v1.1 used one version of the CLR; 2.0, 3.0 & 3.5 used another, and 4.0 uses still another.  So, if you need to run an application that specifically requires the v2.0 CLR, you need to install that also (but in theory, they all should be able to use the v4.0 CLR)

As for upgrading your code, no sense it going through multiple update iteration -- Just upgrade to the latest.